# Student T test Usage differences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

After looking into many blogs, I am completely confused understanding the T-test and the interpretation of the value.
These are my understanding and confusions:

- Student T test is used to compare the Means of two groups
- T test is a Signal to Noise Ratio
- T test validates the sample when the population variance is not known
- T test is used when the sample size is very less

These are the concrete statements used but know one explains the complete usage of T test and how does all these are applicable to use T test.
In the each statement, how to **interpret the t value, t=2.23**, what does this mean?

Finally, what is T test and when to use it? Confused completely with each usage.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your confusion might come from the fact that there are (many) different t-test which all compute the t value slightly different. The t-value itself is a statistic which shows how unlinkely the null hypothesis of the test is. The null hypothesis for an independent 2 sample t-test is that both samples have the same mean. You perform a t-test to see how likely it is that this is actually true (according to your data). The higher the t-value, the less likely it is true (and the lower your p value).

In short: a t-test is used to test if two sets of data are similar (i.e. follow the same distribution). It can do that for different kinds of data and for each type the test is slightly different. For example: there is the independent t-test and the dependent t-test. The independent one will be used if the two samples represent two different sets of observations that are independently drawn (e.g. 2 groups of people, sampled from a population). The dependent one will be used if there is some dependence going on (e.g. one group of people with 2 sets of observations).

The wikipedia page on different forms of t-test can be insightfull.

Comment: More elaboration would be helpful

Comment: Well then. Instead of letting others do the thinking: you could formulate a specific question about something that is unclear to you.